# Why console.log(true&&undefined) return undefined while if(true&&undefined) return false?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
  if(test()&&true){
   console.log("hello");
  }
  console.log(test()&&true);
};

function test(){
}
```

Why console.log(true&&undefined) return undefined while if(true&&undefined) return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(true&&undefined)` doesn't return anything. The [`AND`-expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `true&&undefined` evaluates to `undefined` just as well as the `console.log` argument, and since [`undefined` is a falsy value](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) the [if statement's](http://es5.github.io/#x12.5) body will not get executed.

Comment: thanks a lot!And i have another question,why true&&undefined evaluates to undefined,when two variables are connected by "&&", why undefined not evaluates to false?

Comment: @user2272735: Because JavaScript `&&` does not cast its operands to booleans - it only evaluates the truthiness of the left operand. Read [the article I had linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: I totally got it and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

When using the `&&` operator, the first falsey value is returned.

Since `undefined` is falsey, the `if` statement is evaluated as false.